# Magento - import - Get an error just after clic on save and continue to edit

Tags: magento, import, add-on

My data was move from another server by the team who host my website ( www.whc.ca) and now when i go in the section:

system -> import/export -> [CommerceExtension](http://www.commerceextensions.com/magento-product-import-export.html)

when i open a import with out add any file just clicking save and continue i get this message:

Invalid POST data (please check post_max_size and upload_max_filesize settings in your php.ini file).

I don't get this from any other files in the system -> import/export

I talk with the guy how program this extension and he said that there is nothing in his program that bring this error.

The guys who doing the technical support on WHC do not know how to fix it. It was fix once when i was on the other server but there was no note about how it was fix.

some one made this for me: http://djinncomics.com/phpinfo.php

Can some one know what can cause that or where to look? true the Cpanel i already configure the limit and i modify the php file ether. nothing seem affect this error message.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your import/export extension is certainly overloading some of Magento classes. I got the same error today and checked the code, here is what appear to be the problem, in file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Convert/ProfileController.php :

```
/**
 * Save profile action
 */
public function saveAction()
{
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        ...actions...
    }
    else {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(
            $this->__('Invalid POST data (please check post_max_size and upload_max_filesize settings in your php.ini file).')
        );
        $this->_redirect('*/*');
    }
}
```

When you try to save an import/export profile and don't change any param, Magento will automatically assume that you have a problem with your server configuration, which is not the case.